# Do generators in Javascript generate an iterator or an iterable object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have been reading about iterators and generators a lot lately and from what I have read/seen around, it seems like generators are a syntactic sugar for generating **iterators**. However, in some code examples, I have also seen the returned value of these generators being used as an **iterable**. For example:-

```
function* sampleGenerator() {
 yield 1
 yield 2
 yield 3
}

const it = sampleGenerator()
for (const n of it) {
 console.log(n)
}
```

I assume that in the `for...of` loop, the object after the `of` is an iterable (e.g. arrays, strings etc.). Thus, I am a bit confused about whether the return type is an iterator or an iterable.

Answer (score 3):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Is_a_generator_object_an_iterator_or_an_iterable):

> A generator object is **both** iterator and iterable:

```
let aGeneratorObject = function* () {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}();

console.log(typeof aGeneratorObject.next);
// "function", because it has a next method, so it's an iterator

console.log(typeof aGeneratorObject[Symbol.iterator]);
// "function", because it has an @@iterator method, so it's an iterable

console.log(aGeneratorObject[Symbol.iterator]() === aGeneratorObject);
// true, because its @@iterator method returns itself (an iterator), so it's an well-formed iterable

console.log([...aGeneratorObject]);
// [1, 2, 3]
```